# F# recursive pattern matching method overrides argument

Tags: recursion, f#, arguments, pattern-matching

When building snake in an F# console app, I used the following code to update the console window.

```
//Sets the next character in accumulator
//(i, j) are the coordinates of the game
//(px, py) are the coordinates of snake's head
let rec setConsoleChar acc i j px py =
    if i=px && j=py then
        setConsoleChar (acc+"H") (i+1) j px py
    else
        match i, j with
        | ...
```

But I couldn't help but wonder whether the comparison of `(px, py)` could be in the pattern matching block as well. I tried using the following code, however when hit, the `(i, j)` pointers changed pointing to `(px, py)` which resulted in a faulty return value containing nothing but 'H's.

```
match i, j with
| px, py -> setConsoleChar (acc+"H") (i+1) j px py
| ...
```

*PS: if anyone knows a way to simplify things, please do share.*

Comment: Well, nothing wrong with your first version. In your second case, you will match anyting `i, j` with `px, py` because you are just matching any tuple. You need to put a when guard on it or maybe use an active pattern. See the [Variable Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/pattern-matching-%5bfsharp%5d/)

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this - you need to use something like `|i,j when i=px && j=py`

Comment: Here are some duplicates:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272899/f-odd-pattern-matching-issues  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649541/how-do-i-compare-x-and-y-in-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `px` and `py` inside the match aren't the one given in argument.
They are the matched `i` and `j` and px and py are just the name you choose to give them (shadowing the original px and py)

And by consequence it's i and j disguised in px and py you give to the recursive call instead of the "real" px and py.

Answer (score 0):

There are some comments and an answer that you should take into account. That said, when the conditions are complicated and you end up using a lot of when guards, it might be a good idea to look into [active patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/active-patterns-%5bfsharp%5d/). See below for an example that factors out the equality check. It has the advantage of making the code more readable (usually).

```
let (|MATCH|NOMATCH|) (i,j,px,py) = 
        if i = px && j = py then MATCH
        else
            NOMATCH

let setConsoleChar  (i,j,px,py) =
        match (i,j,px,py) with
        | MATCH -> printfn "%A %A %A %A"  (i+1) j px py
        | NOMATCH -> printfn "%A" "Wot???"


setConsoleChar (1,2,3, 4)
setConsoleChar  (1, 0, 1, 0)
```

> "Wot???" val it : unit = ()
>    2 0 1 0 val it : unit = ()